# How to I generate a thread dump for an Java process on heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

I want to be able to generate a java thread dump for my Java application running on heroku? I saw that heroku has jstack running but I can't figure out how to run it to generate a thread dump on my process. I can't figure out how to get the PID to send to jstack. Once I have the PID to I simply run "heroku jstack -l " from my dev machine (it has toolbelt installed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so here is the best way to do it. This will give you the format that JVM uses instead of having to recreate it programmatically. Again, this is for heroku, other environments will need to adjust this code. This exposes it as a rest interface.

```
@GET
@Transactional
@Path( "/threaddump" )
public Response threadDump() throws Exception {
    dumpThreads();
    return Response.ok().build();
}

public static void dumpThreads() throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/sh", "-c", "kill -3 $PPID" );
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream( true );
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    StreamUtils.copy( inputStream, System.out );
}
```

Comment: is that org.springframework.util.StreamUtils ? and what is Response type? why not write the output to a file ? just curious. I understood the kill -3 part but wondering about why you choose this method to get the response back.

Comment: I wanted it in my papertrail log I also want it to respond just like Ctrl-Break would. Don't really want it in a file. Not sure I understand your question about the Response type. On the StreamUtils you can also use Guava CharStreams.toString(in) and just send that to the LOG or System.out.

Comment: in your function public Response threadDump() throws Exception {, what is the full name of this Response class - I'm not familiar with it. so this prints the result to the app system out?

Comment: Oh, I'm just using JAX-RS Jersey. This is a Response class they have.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following - put this function in some class and have a way to call it, save the output to a file or show it on a page ...

```
static StringBuilder allStack() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> trace = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    for(Thread t:trace.keySet()){
        StackTraceElement[]trc = trace.get(t);
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(t.getName());
        sb.append(" ");         
        sb.append(t.getId());

        sb.append(" |");            
        sb.append(t.getThreadGroup());

        sb.append("| ");            
        sb.append(t);
        sb.append(" :-\n");
        for(StackTraceElement e:trc){
            sb.append(e.toString());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append(" -***-\n");
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do this. But I didn't want to do it programmatically. I want to do it from the console. So for a web server running on a Heroku dyno, I want to generate a thread dump from my local box.

Comment: no idea. it is more powerful -> if process is hung. why not ask via a ticket in your host?

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider embedding a REST API to java JMX to perform this thread dump. Jolokia seems a good candidate. It will support built-in authentication as well and be more flexible in that you can access any JMX mbean without having to implement new REST end points

See 
http://www.jolokia.org and specifically the REST protocol to invoke the [ThreadMXBean.dumpAllThreads()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#dumpAllThreads%28boolean,%20boolean%29) method using the [POST Exec request](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html#post-exec)